# Set src to an ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want set an image to my ImageView created dynamically in my android app.
I simply create it :

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
```

and I want to set an image from a link like

[image: example image]

What have I to do ?

EDIT: my code:

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.article, null);



                img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
                url=thumbnail;

                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(img);
```

It is in a for cicle

Comment: there are tons of tutorial for rendering image to a imageview. You can also use libraries like picasso.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Comment: check this out https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/miscellaneous/list/activities/ImageViewDynamicallyActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3rd party 
http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
Picasso.with(context).load("imageURL").into(image);
```

add dependency in **Gradle**

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: Picasso cause me freeze on app interface...

Answer (score 1):

You need to get that image from the net.

I recommend you to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Add it to your project putting this line into the dependences in your Gradle file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

And displayed with:

```
Picasso.with(this).load("URL").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Picasso cause me freeze on app interface...

Comment: The image is really huge?

Comment: fullHD or HD, but only 600kb

Comment: Picasso don't block the ui thread, somthing else is causing you this error. Can you post your code?

Comment: I add the code in the answer

Comment: I discovered that one or two imgage are in 4k resolution, and picasso can' t load it. I tried with .resize() but nothing...

Answer (score 0):

From an online source? Something along these lines: `image.setImageUri(Uri.parse("http://..."))`

Comment: This is not a good choice, as downloading the image will be done on the main application thread, freezing the UI.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has mentioned how to use `Piccaso` , I would like to mention the question is more focused on how to add this `ImageView` dynamically to the `Layout`, you can certainlly check the code on [github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/miscellaneous/list/activities/ImageViewDynamicallyActivity.java), it's been tested.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewDynamicallyActivity_linear_layout);
// this would be the linear layout to which you can add the `ImageView`

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
// you can make a lot of changes to the `imageview` attributes here
linearLayout.addView(imageView);

Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://image.3bmeteo.com/images/newarticles/w_663/immagine-nasa-visible-infrared-imaging-radiometer-suite-viirs-3bmeteo-66721.jpg").into(imageView);
```

I am assuming you would have added `Picasso` dependency to your `build.gradle`  file for the app module.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: Picasso cause me freeze on app interface...

Comment: @MarcoGhigo, i don't think so that using picasso would freeze the UI, I think it takes time to load the image from the URI